# Google Play - Will the playstore link to my beta app be the same as the production link?

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an app and am currently testing it as open test (Beta).
The app is available when users have the link to the appstore which is in this format:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tld.domain.subdomain

*tld.domain.subdomain* is my package name.

My question simply is: Once I promoted my beta version to production release, **will the link above stay the same as for the beta test?**

I want to know this (without publishing it now) because I want to print some flyers with QR Codes to my App once it is released. Probably a stupid question but I am not able to test this myself right now because the app is not finished yet and I want to be sure to print the correct QR Codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Links to the Google Play store are basically their package names.

The way people enter Google Play Beta testing is if they join the Beta program on Google Play. The application/package name is the same, so the link to the app will be too.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. I assumed already that the link will stay the same once I publish my app. But was not sure 100% since it is my first app in the play store.